# Field not showing error in Agile Toolkit

Tags: atk4, php

trying to use the beforeSave hook with some server side validation and throwing a field error - and it is working ..... kind of ....

There is an exception caused because it doesn't save as required and the base exception can be viewed with the right message if no field is defined. If I define field then I don't see the error popup or the error info on the crud form.

To be clear, its not letting me save and throwing the exception. When I use `setField('fiscal_year')` Its still not saving as per the exception, its just not **displaying** the exception.

Code below:

```
class Model_Finances extends Model_Table {
    public $table='finances';

    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Grant');

        $this->addField('fiscal_year')->datatype('int');
        $this->addField('requested')->datatype('money');
        $this->addField('committed')->datatype('money');
        $this->addField('spent')->datatype('money');

        $this->getField('grant')->hidden(true);

        $this->addHook('beforeSave',$this);
    }

    function beforeSave($model){
        $exist = $this->api->db->dsql()
                      ->table($this->table)
                      ->field('count(1)')
                      ->where('grant_id', 2) //manually set ID for testing.
                      ->where('fiscal_year', $model['fiscal_year'])
                      ->do_getOne();
        // Validate fiscal year before saving
        if($exist[0]) {
            throw $this->exception('Fiscal year for this grant already exists')->setField('fiscal_year');
        }
    }
}
```

How it's being used:

```
    $finances = $grant->ref('Finances');
    $finances->getField('fiscal_year')->setValueList($this->fiscalYears)->mandatory(true);
    $crud=$tabs->addTab('Finances')->add('CRUD');
    $crud->setModel($finances);
    if($crud->grid)$crud->grid->addTotals(array('requested', 'committed', 'spent'));
```

Comment: Are you saving in a form? Try using `$form->onSubmit(function($f){ $f->update()->js()->univ()->successMessage('All ok')->execute; });`

Comment: Hi @romaninsh its being saved from a CRUD element.

Comment: Added more code to show usage @romaninsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite difficult to reproduce the problem, so I created a test-case out of it.

I have changed only this line:

```
throw $this->exception('Fiscal year for this grant already exists','ValidityCheck')
    ->setField('fiscal_year');
```

and here is result

[image]

- Example: http://test-suite.agiletoolkit.org/?page=issue/so3655
- Code: https://github.com/atk4/atk4-testsuite/blob/master/page/issue/so3655.php

If you submit form like this:

```
$form->onSubmit(function($f){
    $f->model->blah();
});
```

Then exceptions generated inside model->blah will also show up nicely.

Comment: That worked! - I don't remember reading about the 'ValidityCheck' anywhere, strange.

Comment: ValidityCheck really does the trick! This is great - so, we can normally move all important validations to model level where they actually belong.
In this particular case (and maybe in testsuite too) it's probably needs to add more where clauses as I mentioned above in my comment: id!=$model->id AND grant_id=$model[grant_id] AND fiscal_year=$model[$fiscal_year] or something like that. Otherwise it's impossible to edit existing grant and also you can't add more than one (different) grant in one year.
+1

Comment: One more thing to note is, that model -> exception('...','ValidityCheck') only works if it's inside beforeSave hook and not in other functions of model.

Comment: yes, or you could call them from inside `$form->onSubmit(function($f){  $f->model->blah(); });`  Then it will also catch the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll not fully answer your question, because I'm quite a beginner in ATK4 too, but

First of all I guess you shouldn't use $_GET in Model level. I believe it should be something like grant_id=$model['grant_id'].

Second, as far as I understood you want to check that for one Grant there is unique fiscal years? If so, then you should add two more conditions to WHERE (see below) or like that.

As result I believe your query should be something like this (just a pseudo code):

```
$exist = $this->api->db->dsql()
                   ->table($this->table)
                   ->field('count(*)') // I guess it can be written as ->count() too
                   ->where('grant_id',$model['grant_id'])
                   ->where('id','!=',$model->id)
                   ->where('fiscal_year',$model['fiscal_year'])
                   ->do_getOne();
if($exist[0]) {
    throw $this->exception('Fiscal year for this grant already exists')
               ->setField('fiscal_year');
}
```

Speaking about throwing exception associated with a form field, I guess you should somehow add that using Form Field validation hooks. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Still not working. This stops the saving as required, just doesn't show the error on the field.

Comment: As I said before:
Speaking about throwing exception associated with a form field, I guess you should somehow add that using Form Field validation hooks. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Maybe you should check out this issue. Maybe it's fixed in latest ATK4 version in Github. There was one fix for atk4_form.js last week. Maybe that'll help in your situation too - check out!

Comment: Thanks @DarkSide got the latest version but still nothing.